# laying out a row of localized buttons over the full width of the screen

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I need a row with 5 buttons spread over the full width of the phone screen. The text displayed on each button is set depending on the locale setting: it is retrieved from resource files using the `GetString` method of a `ResourceLoader`. What should be the XAML code for those buttons and their container so that

- the 5 buttons use the full width of the screen
- fontsize is the same for all 5 buttons
- no button content is truncated (think to the English/German versions of the same text)
- spacing between the buttons (padding or margin) is constant

**** EDIT ****

After reviewing the documentation mentioned by Jerry below, I modified my XAML code and resource files as follows:

```
        <Grid >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Uid="analyzeBtnCol"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Uid="suggestBtnCol"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Uid="stepBtnCol"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Uid="undoBtnCol"/>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Uid="solveBtnCol"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="analyzeBtn" Grid.Column="0" x:Uid="analyzeBtn" Padding="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="AnalyseBtnFired" FontSize="10" />
            <Button x:Name="suggestBtn" Grid.Column="1" x:Uid="suggestBtn" Padding="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="SuggestBtnFired" FontSize="10" />
            <Button x:Name="stepBtn" Grid.Column="2" x:Uid="stepBtn" Padding="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="StepBtnFired" FontSize="10" />
            <Button x:Name="undoBtn" Grid.Column="3" x:Uid="undoBtn" Padding="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="UndoBtnFired" FontSize="10" />
            <Button x:Name="solveBtn" Grid.Column="4" x:Uid="solveBtn" Padding="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="SolveBtnFired" FontSize="10" />
        </Grid>
```

"en-US" resource file extract:

```
  <data name="solveBtnCol.Width" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>7*</value>
  </data>
  <data name="solveBtn.Content" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Solve</value>
  </data>
  <data name="solveBtn.FontSize" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>13</value>
  </data>
```

"nl-NL" resource file extract:

```
  <data name="solveBtnCol.Width" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>10*</value>
  </data>
  <data name="solveBtn.Content" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Oplossen</value>
  </data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic XAML you want:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Uid="Button1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Button1" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.DoButton1}" />
    <Button x:Uid="Button2" Grid.Column="1" Content="Button2" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.DoButton2}" />
    <Button x:Uid="Button3" Grid.Column="2" Content="Button3" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.DoButton3}" />
    <Button x:Uid="Button4" Grid.Column="3" Content="Button4" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.DoButton4}" />
    <Button x:Uid="Button5" Grid.Column="4" Content="Button5" Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.DoButton5}" />
</Grid>
```

And notice the x:Uid part. This maps to the string you use in your Resources file where you handle localization. Here's more information on how to do that.

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965329(v=win.10).aspx

Best of luck

Answer (score 2):

Typically you don't need code behind to localize `Button` captions and use `x:Uid` then key the string resource in the resw file with `YourButtonXuid.Content`.

Other than that it seems to be more of a design question than programming question, although these things often cross over. You could put your buttons in a `Grid` with equal-star-sized columns to support your conditions 1,2,4, but exactly for the risk of truncation reasons and especially on the phone - you would never do that. Phone screen is wide enough to display 4-5 buttons that are identified by icons, but if you want to show text then you can't possibly expect to fit them all across the screen unless they only have small text captions akin to app bar buttons which I think trim their text if it's too long anyway.

I'd consider either

- Ensuring the localized text length is limited or
- Using a different layout or control

Comment: Horizontal streched stackpanel wouldn't be an option? because he/she never asked for equal width buttons and set maxwidth for the buttons.

Comment: Blasphemy!:) But you're right. He or she didn't say that. A StackPanel will use less space, but still doesn't solve the problem and looks ugly.

Comment: Blasphemy?! Lol! xD Just a suggestion though. Trying to be specific about condition number 3. Ugly agreed (Y)

Comment: I am new to c# and I did not know about x:Uid. After reviewing the above doc and some trial and error I came to a quite satisfying solution: I added an `x:Uid="xxx"` attribute in the `ColumnDefinition` and a `xxx.Width` string in each resource file where the width value is roughly equal to the length of the related string (requires some tuning for proportional fonts). See EDIT in the question.